# Clone <li> and throw with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

We have:

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

How do I get second half of this list and move it before first `<li>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var ul = $('ul');
var lis = ul.children('li');

ul.prepend(lis.slice(Math.round(lis.length / 2)))
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8SNGn/

This first caches the `<ul>` element and its `<li>` children using the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

Then it uses the [`prepend()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method to add the last `li` elements to the beginning of the `ul`.

You get the last ones by using the [`slice()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method and passing it the total number of `li` elements divided by 2 (rounded up using `Math.round()` for when you have odd number).

---

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that your question title has the word *"clone"* in it.

The rest of the question doesn't seem to suggest it, but if you really wanted to clone the last half, you'd use the [`clone()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

```
var ul = $('ul');
var lis = ul.find('li');

ul.prepend(lis.slice(Math.round(lis.length / 2)).clone())
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8SNGn/1/

And if you want the rounding to go the other direction, you'd use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.round`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = $("ul li");
items.filter(function(index) {
    return index > items.length / 2;
}).prependTo($("ul")[0]);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var len = $('li').length - 1;

for(var i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
    var $li = $('li').eq(len);
    $('ul').prepend($li);

}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/NiceGuy4263/Ws5ZK/

Answer (score 0):

jquery prepend http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery's .slice() filter:

http://api.jquery.com/slice